# Is there a way to set a lock on AtomicReference

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to do this:

- read a value in AtomicReference
- based on the old value execute a complex logic to create a new value
- replace the value in the AtomicReference

During this process I want other threads to wait until this is finished. So I need to put a read lock on the thread and release the lock after the logic is completed.

Provided below is my attempt:

```
AtomicReference<String> version = new AtomicReference<>();
String v = version.get(); // Is there way to put a read lock here so that when other thread try to read it, they will have to wait until the current thread finish
if (v.equals("old")) { 
   String newVersion = getNewVersion(); // execute a complex logic
   version.set(newVersion);
}
// release the lock here
```

Comment: this is _exactly_ what `AtomicReference::updateAndGet` is for. Just read it's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blocking all reading threads (via `get`) like that is not possible. You'd need to use additional tools for doing that and you'd need to use them everywhere you use `version`.

The *closest* thing to your idea is to use an atomic method of `AtomicReference` like `updateAndGet`:

```java
AtomicReference<String> version = new AtomicReference<>();
version.updateAndGet(v -> {
    if (v.equals("old")) {
        return getNewVersion();
    }
    else {
        return v;
    }
});
```

This method utilizes the atomic [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) instruction to achieve [non-blocking synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm).

A simple implementation of this method would be:

```java
public T updateAndGet(UnaryOperator<T> f) {
    T curr, next;
    do {
        curr = get();
        next = f.apply(curr);
    } while (!compareAndSet(curr, next));
    return next;
}
```

The method `compareAndSet` (that is the facade for accessing the underlying CAS instruction) returns `true` if the first given argument equals the actual current value, otherwise `false`. If the first given argument equals the actual current value, the current value is replaced by the second argument (*compare and swap*).

Now why do I explain this? Because using `updateAndGet` is close to what you want, but not the same:

- It can happen that `getNewVersion` runs more that one time. This happens when the current value is changed by another thread in-between `curr = get();` and the CAS call.
- Reads that happen in between `curr = get();` and the CAS call get the old value, not the new one like in your idea. But this timespan is small, you should not worry about it.
- No locks are involved, which is by the way one of the greatest benefits of using `AtomicXXX` classes. You want them to be lightweight and fast.

Comment: Just to make it clear: this does not lock the `AtomicReference`, as that’s impossible. It’s just syntactic sugar for the `String old; do { old = version.get(); } while(old.equals("old") && !version.compareAndSet(old, getNewVersion()));` loop that you would have used before Java 8. Btw, you can simplify it to `version.updateAndGet(v -> v.equals("old")? getNewVersion(): v);`